# Javascript modal image zoom

Tags: javascript, zooming

I have an image modal. Something like facebook has in messenger for displaying images. I want to add zoom-in and zoom-out buttom- something like pdf viewer ?on gmail? has. How could i zoom in and out image, with buttons, using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you want to zoom it. You can zoom it by modifying the `width` and `height` of the `img` tag. If that is not an option, for example your modal has a fixed size, then you can change the [transform](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp) property. You want to scale it. Since this is a CSS property, let's see an example with CSS rules which is based on this scaling idea:

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="http://someurl/0v15321t3W1a/pepsi.jpg" alt="pepsi" width="540" height="548">

  <div class="item-overlay top"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  position: relative;

  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 540px;
}
.item img {
  max-width: 100%;

  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.item:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

Taken from [here](https://codepen.io/afinedayproductions/pen/EzvLp). Note that CSS attributes can be modified in Javascript using the `style` attribute of the given tag.